# How to handle api responses with null values? Kotlin

Tags: json, kotlin

Ive been trying to handle this kind of situation where the api call response gives me this type of response and I no longer know how I will handle it. The response sometimes exposes a value and sometimes a null resulting for app to crash. The api also changes depending in the situation. Sometime the field is not there, sometime its there but has a value of null, and sometimes has a value of empty string. Do you know any work around to handle this situation?

Api response:

"valrep_landimp_lot_details": [
    {
      "valrep_landimp_propdesc_area": "1000",
      "valrep_landimp_propdesc_block": null,
      "valrep_landimp_propdesc_lot": "3",
      "valrep_landimp_propdesc_lot_classification": null,
      "valrep_landimp_propdesc_place": null,
      "valrep_landimp_propdesc_registered_owner": "RANK A",
      "valrep_landimp_propdesc_registry_date_day": "01",
      "valrep_landimp_propdesc_registry_date_month": "01",
      "valrep_landimp_propdesc_registry_date_year": "1980",
      "valrep_landimp_propdesc_registry_of_deeds": "Makati City",
      "valrep_landimp_propdesc_survey_nos": null,
      "valrep_landimp_propdesc_tct_no": "T-33333"
    }
  ]

Data class:

```
@field:SerializedName("valrep_landimp_propdesc_block")
val valrepLandimpPropdescBlock: String? = null
```

How call the variable:

```
           it?.valrepLandimpPropdescBlock!!
```

Error :  kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException

Thank you in advance!

Comment: where does your application crash? On parsing the JSON? what code do you use to read the response?

Comment: Yes please post your code where you are using this variable

Comment: Whether null is possible, and what that would mean, will depend on the API you're calling.  But if null is a possibility, then your client should be able to handle it.  — Also, [it's helpful](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/10134209) if you can post the code, data, and any errors as text, not as images.

Comment: Hello sir. I just edited my question for more information about my problem. Thank you